# Erwin Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications, Section 2.6, Problem 11

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, matrix-equations

Let $X$ be the vector space of all complex $n \times n$ matrices and define $T \colon X \to X$ by $Tx \colon= bx$, where $b \in X$ is fixed and $bx$ denotes the usual product of matrices. I know that $T$ is linear.

Under what conditions does $T^{-1}$ exist?

If $b$ is an invertible matrix, then of course $T^{-1}$ exists.

But does the existence of $T^{-1}$ necessarily imply the invertibility of the matrix $b$?

What condition(s) (other than invertibility), if any, should $b$ satisfy in order for $T^{-1}$ to exist?

Comment: Knowing this fact about square matrices might also be useful for this questions: [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $T$ has inverse $T^{-1}$. Then $T$ is an injective map between finite dimensional vector spaces. The [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) then implies the map is surjective, so PhoemueX's argument may be applied.

Comment: Ok, if one only means "injective" by "invertible", then one also has to apply this reasoning. One similar point: My proof above only shows that the matrix $b$ has a right inverse. But by similar arguments (which I wanted the OP to figure out himself), this suffices to conclude that $b$ is actually invertible. +1.

Answer (score 3):

If $T$ is invertible, there is some $x$ such that $bx = Tx = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix (why?).

Hence?

Comment: But $T$ could well be invertible even if the identity matrix is not in the range of $T$, couldn't it?

Comment: For a (single-valued) mapping to be invertible, it is sufficient for the mapping to be injective. Am I right?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud It this is the case, you should explain in your posts what is your definition of invertible/inverse/$T^{-1}$. But the definition, which is used most frequently, means that only bijective maps are invertible. See: [Inverse of a Function exists iff Function is bijective](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994282/inverse-of-a-function-exists-iff-function-is-bijective). For injective/surjective functions you can find at least one-sided inverse: [Left inverse iff injective; right inverse iff surjective](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553186/).

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Having said that, in your case $T\colon X\to X$ is a *linear* map and $X$ is *finite-dimentional*. For such maps, if $T$ is injective then it also is surjective (hence bijective).